# JQuery Datatables reloading data with child rows

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to replicate the functionality shown here:

[JQuery Datatables - Child Rows](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

This works perfectly using the code shown below:

```
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td width="100px" style="padding:3px"><strong>Assigned To:</strong></td>'+
        '<td style="padding:3px">'+d.assignedto+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td style="padding:3px"><strong>Area:</strong></td>'+
        '<td style="padding:3px">'+d.area+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td style="padding:3px"><strong>Category:</strong></td>'+
        '<td style="padding:3px">'+d.category+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td style="padding:3px"><strong>Notes:</strong></td>'+
        '<td style="padding:3px">'+d.notes+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#btn-getorder" ).click( function(event) {
    var table = $('#tbl-l250-tickets').DataTable( {
        retrieve: true,
        "ajax": "ajax-get-last250tickets.php?cust-code="+$("#hid-cust-id").val(),
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "ticketid" },
            { "data": "orderno" },
            { "data": "issue" },
            { "data": "receiveddate" },
            { "data": "completeddate" },
            { "data": "notesshort" }
        ]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#tbl-l250-tickets tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
});
```

});

The problem I have is, if a new order number is entered, and the page is regenerated with new data, the child row expansion is failing with 'd is undefined' in the 'format' function.

Having stepped through the code, it looks as though the 'row' variable is empty when the format function is called on the new table. It works for the first order loaded into the page, but fails for any subsequent.

I don't understand why this should be the case.

I have also tried explicitly destroying the table with the following:

```
if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#tbl-l250-tickets' ) ) {
        table = $('#tbl-l250-tickets').DataTable();
        table.destroy();
    };
```

before the table is re-created, but this hasn't helped either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `$('#tbl-l250-tickets tbody').off('click', 'td.details-control')` before `$('#tbl-l250-tickets tbody').on('click', ...)` to detach event handler or move it outside of the click event handler for `#btn-getorder`.

Comment: Tried this but exactly the same. Firebug shows the 'row' variable as populated on the first use, but when a new dataset is loaded its empty. Just can't see where the values are being discarded.

Comment: CORRECTION - strange, but seems to be working now. Have added in the `$('#tbl-l250-tickets tbody').off('click', 'td.details-control')` as suggested, and it works fine. Commenting this out stops it from working again. If you would like to add this as an answer I will mark as accepted. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching event handler for `td.details-control` every time user clicks `#btn-getorder`.

Try detaching the handler first:

```
// Detach event listener
$('#tbl-l250-tickets tbody').off('click', 'td.details-control');

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#tbl-l250-tickets tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
   // ... 
});
```

Even better solution would be to move event handler outside of the click event handler for `#btn-getorder`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#btn-getorder" ).click( function(event) {
      // ... 
   });

   // Add event listener for opening and closing details
   $('#tbl-l250-tickets tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
      // ... 
   });
});
```

Comment: Detaching the handler and re-adding it works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Could you pelase hav e look at [Cannot list details data in jQuery Datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998706/cannot-list-details-data-in-jquery-datatable)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Gyrocode.com No, I just upvoted you and other helpful people like you :) Voted+++